# How can I remove substrings that start with 'a' till next 'b'?

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string:

```
a = "select * from ABC -- where  A = B \n And D = C \n -- And  X = Y \n And J = I;"
```

I want to remove all substrings that start with `"--"` till the next `"\n"`. So after editing above string, `a` will be:

```
a = "select * from ABC  And D = C \n  And J = I;"
```

Comment: `gsub` with a regex makes this easy.

Comment: Why is `"-- And  X = Y \n And J = I;"` removed? Yes, it begins with `"--"`, but there is no newline character.

Comment: What if you string is, let's say `"select * from ABC where A = '--' and D = C"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`String#gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21)

```
a = "select * from ABC -- where A = B \n And D = C \n -- And X = Y \n And J = I;"
a.gsub(/--.*\n/, "") #=> "select * from ABC  And D = C \n  And J = I;"
```

It's possible because of newline character.

**More general way**

For example you need to remove substring starting with `"foo"` and ending with `"bar"`.

```
a = "aaafoobb\nbbarcccfoodd\tdbareee"
a.gsub(/foo(.*?)bar/m, "") #=> "aaaccceee"
```

Comment: `a.gsub!(/--.*\n/, "")` returns the same result as `a` after `a` is altered. You might explain why you've included `a` as the last statement. Another option: `a.tap { |s| s.gsub!(/--.*\n/, "") }`.

Comment: I was thinking you did it for another reason: that `gsub!` returns `nil` if the receiver is not changed (hence my reference to `tap`).

Comment: Notice that this answer works particularly because the matching pattern ends with a newline character, which `.` in the regex does not match in the regex mode used. If it were a different pattern, the regex needs extra care to avoid greedy match.

Comment: @sawa you are right, I added information to my answer

Comment: I just noticed one thing. gsub! returns nil if string doesn't contain "--" or "\n" but as @CarySwoveland suggested, tap works.